# Reading mix between numeric and non-numeric data from excel into Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a matrix where the first column contains dates and the first row contains maturities which are alpha/numeric (e.g. 16year).

The rest of the cells contain the rates for each day, which are double precision numbers.

Now I believe `xlsread()` can only handle numeric data so I think I will need something else or a combination of functions?

I would like to be able to read the table from excel into MATLAB as one array or perhaps a `struct()` so that I can keep all the data together.

The other problem is that some of the rates are given as '#N/A'. I want the cells where these values are stored to be kept but would like to change the value to `blank=" "`.
What is the best way to do this? Can it be done as part of the input process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from looking at [matlab reference for xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbmn) you can use the format

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(FILENAME)
```

and then you will have in **num** a matrix of your data, in **txt** the unreadable data, i.e. your text headers, and in **raw** you will have all of your data unprocessed. (including the text headers).

So I guess you could use the **raw** array, or a combination of the **num** and **txt**.

For your other problem, if your rates are 'pulled' from some other source, you can use

```
=IFERROR(RATE DATA,"")
```

and then there will be a blank instead of the error code `#N\A`.

Another solution (only for Windows) would be to use `xlsread()` format which allows running a function on your imported data,

```
[num,txt,raw,custom] = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange,'',functionHandler)
```

and let the function replace the `NaN` values with blank spots. (and you will have your output in the **custom** array)